# Flutter - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

In "flutter doctor" it shows everything is OK, but with "flutter run" - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the folder `android` in your project folder, then re-running `flutter build appbundle` or `flutter build apk`?

Comment: The error clearly says that it cannot find the iclauncher, just check if you have deleted it or changes the name.

Answer (score 0):

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1